# Xcode hangs indefinitely when adding constraints in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

## In summary, without height specified on a subview, adding constraint causes Xcode to hang.

I am using **Xcode 6.3 (6D570)** on Macbook Air with OSX 10.10.3, and am currently experiencing a very strange problem. I have an .xib file, which contains a view and a scroll view. Very simple, really. Here's my current setup:

[image: Xcode Interface Builder screenshot]

Notice that the light blue/green section downwards are contained in a scroll view. In the interface builder, the bright red section does not have constraints set yet. **When I try to add, for example, a vertical space constraint to the lightgray view above it, Xcode hangs.**

When Xcode hangs, the Size inspector tab becomes empty and the mouse starts spinning endlessly. Here's the Size inspector screenshot when the hang happens:

[image: hanging xcode]

After spending almost half a day, I managed to single out the problem. This problem does not happen if I add the constraints via **Pin** button on the bottom right corner, *and* specifying the height constraint of the view.

[image: Pin screenshot]

Adding constraints only work as expected if I specify / add a height constraint first. This also happens when I try to delete a constraint, for example, top space to container constraint from a label (that does not have a height constraint). I can add them just fine, **but when I try to remove a constraint or delete the view, Xcode hangs.**

Oh, to add more confusion: this happens *frequently*. As in 7 hangs out of 10.

Things I have tried:

- Remaking the view on different file
- Remaking the view on different project
- Closing all applications except Xcode, including iOS Simulator
- Restarting my computer

Things I have **not** tried:

- Reinstalling Xcode (or rolling back to previous version).

Should I just delete Xcode and install (download) fresh? Is this possibly a bug from the new Xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there's a bug within Xcode 6.3.0. There's an update to 6.3.1 Apr 21, 2015 that should fix this issue:

[image: xcode update]